# Problem reading elements from file usint matrix

Tags: c, matrix, fread

I'm using a funtion in order to store an 11K line text and i am having several problems.
It does not read the file and "printf("\nOut of the loop");" dont even appear when compiling

```
typedef struct{
    int dia, mes, anho;
}Date;

typedef struct{
    Date fecha;
    float longitud, latitud, elevacion, temperaturaMax, temperaturaMin, precipitacion, viento, humedad, solar;
}WeatherData;

WeatherData** LeerCSVcrearweatherdata(char binaryname[],int linecounter);

int main(){
WeatherData **datos=malloc(contadorlineas*sizeof(WeatherData));
datos=LeerCSVcrearweatherdata(nombrebinario,linecounter); //linecounter comes from another function, it is not here but it works




WeatherData** LeerCSVcrearweatherdata(char binaryname[],int linecounter){ 
    WeatherData **datos;
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen(nombrebinario,"rb"); This works correctly
    datos=(WeatherData**)malloc(sizeof(WeatherData));
    
    
    for (int i=0;i<linecounter;i++){
        datos[i]=malloc(sizeof(WeatherData*));
        fread(datos[i],sizeof(WeatherData),1,f);
    }
    
    printf("\nOut of the loop");
    printf("%d",datos[0]->fecha.dia);
    fclose(f);
    return datos; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can see on this line  `f=fopen(nombrebinario,"rb");` I think that u forgot to put the extension `.dat` on `nombrebinario`

Comment: I see your point, let me explain the issue. Previously I have worked with another function where I read the name of the file which has csv extension. Later I create another file with the same name but with .dat extension (using strcat() so i could just copy the original name and add ".dat" at the end,, in order to "change" the file extension).
I dont know if I explai it correctly, do want me to copy here all my program? I mean, the problem is just with that funtion, everyelse works